# JobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions does not work correctly

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In a project I use spring-batch, as a part of cleanup for processes that stuck I use 
`JobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(...)` 
but that function return empty set. After digging I found next problem: spring-batch use SQL like 
`SELECT E.JOB_EXECUTION_ID, ... from %PREFIX%JOB_EXECUTION E ... WHERE ... E.END_TIME is NULL ...`. After running long job, I got that from beginning 3 Dates in %PREFIX%JOB_EXECUTION (CREATE_TIME, START_TIME, END_TIME) have same value. This mean that SQL will always return empty set.

Question is, am I one who get this?
How to report bug to Spring team?

Comment: That isn't a bug.  I'd have to hear more about how your `JobExplorer` is configured to determine where things are going wrong.

Comment: Concept itself is simple: I know that my job executed f.e. max for 10 min. So I go thru all running jobs and if one of them older than 10 min - this job is stuck. I use JobOperator to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the Spring batch project [home page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/)

Jira's can be Entered [here](http://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH)

Not sure what version you are running, but with version 2.1.1 (which is real old I know) but this code works.

```
jobOperator.getRunningExecutions(String jobName)
```

Here is the javadoc from that version

```
 /**
     * Get the id values of all the running {@link JobExecution JobExecutions}
     * with the given job name.
     * 
     * @param jobName the name of the job to search under
     * @return the id values of the running {@link JobExecution} instances
     * @throws NoSuchJobException if there are no {@link JobExecution
     * JobExecutions} with that job name
     */
    Set<Long> getRunningExecutions(String jobName) throws NoSuchJobException;
```

Link to the most update [JobOperator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/JobOperator.java)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use last one: 3.0.2.RELEASE